# Does Readiness check keep running after a pod has been marked unready?

Tags: kubernetes, healthcheck

My understanding is that after waiting for 45 seconds, Kubernetes is going to hit /heartbeat and wait for the response for 5 seconds. If it doesn't get the response, it is going to try 5 times(every 60 seconds). After 5x60seconds=5mins has elapsed, is Kubernetes going to keep doing the readiness check? If the service comes up after 6 mins, Is this pod going to be marked as ready? Second question, does it keep using failureThreshold and other readiness settings?

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /heartbeat
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 45
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 60
  failureThreshold: 5
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /summary
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 180
  timeoutSeconds: 1
  periodSeconds: 60
  failureThreshold: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

In general it's correct:

- readines probe **will be initiated after: initialDelaySeconds: 45** # (delay) Number of seconds after the container has started before liveness or readiness probes are initiated.
- **periodSeconds: 60 # (How often in seconds) to perform the probes**. Default to 10 seconds. Minimum value is 1.
- **timeoutSeconds: 5 # (time to response)** Number of seconds after which the probe times out. Defaults to 1 second. Minimum value is 1,
- **failureThreshold: 5  # (how many attempts will do) before giving up)** In case of readiness probe the Pod will be marked Unready. Defaults to 3. Minimum value is 1,

When **failureThreshold for livenes probe will be reached - kubelet** will automatically perform the **correct action in accordance with the Pod’s restartPolicy**,

Once the failureThreshold for readinesprobe will be raeched the Pod will be marked as **Unready**. ( Defaults to 3. Minimum value is 1.).

**As per documentation**:

> 1. When a Pod is not ready, it is removed from Service load balancers.
> 2. Note: Readiness probes runs on the container during its whole lifecycle.

resources:

- [Configure Liveness and Readiness Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/)
- [Container probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes)